# Postgres - How to create index for simple association directly (outside of activerecord)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

We have a Postgres database that is populated through a node app that parses XML and loads our dataset for us.

We have built a Sinatra app to view the data. We have a number of `archive_objects` which have a number of `tags`.

We have associated the two classes via their models, eg:

```
class ArchiveObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :archive_objects
end
```

We have noticed that calling, for example `current_archive_object.tags` is quite slow (400+ms on average), and after reading [Using indexes in rails: Index your associations](https://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-index-your-associations), I see the recommendation to create the index for this simple association in the ActiveRecord migration (names modified for relevance here):

`add_index :tags, :archive_object_id, :name => 'archive_object_id_idx'`

**I'm wondering, how can I create this index directly in `psql` since our database is not generated through an AR migration?**

**EDIT**:
Information regarding our 'junction table', should it be relevant

```
\d+ archive_objects_tags
                               Table "public.archive_objects_tags"
      Column       |           Type           | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description
-------------------+--------------------------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 created_at        | timestamp with time zone | not null  | plain   |              |
 updated_at        | timestamp with time zone | not null  | plain   |              |
 tag_id            | integer                  | not null  | plain   |              |
 archive_object_id | integer                  | not null  | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "archive_objects_tags_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (tag_id, archive_object_id)
Has OIDs: no
```

And the SQL call from the rack console:

`Tag Load (397.4ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "archive_objects_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "archive_objects_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "archive_objects_tags"."archive_object_id" = $1  [["archive_object_id", 4823]]`

Comment: you can create a migration to add the index. for example in migration put
`def change` 
`add_index :table, :column_to_be_indexed`
`end`

Answer (score 0):

From [the PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html), the equivalent to

`add_index :tags, :archive_object_id, :name => 'archive_object_id_idx'`

would be:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX archive_object_id_idx ON tags (archive_object_id);`

I don't believe that is what you want in your case, because your tags table does not have an archive_object_id column. You probably want to create a [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) on your "junction table".

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX archive_objects_tags_tag_id_archive_object_id_idx ON archive_objects_tags (archive_object_id, tag_id);`